Qiskit: Superposition of Three States with Unequal Amplitudes
I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following (in Qiskit):

Preparing a superposition of three states
Setting the amplitude of each state to a particular value
Carrying out a specific number of measurements in said system

Would be very very grateful if someone could give me a hand with what the code should look like - thanks!

Sure, here's an example where you measure 1000 times the following state:
$$ |\psi \rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} |00\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{6}} |01\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{3}{6}} |11\rangle $$
from math import sqrt
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

samples = 1000

state = Statevector([sqrt(1/6), sqrt(2/6), 0, sqrt(3/6)])
counts = state.sample_counts(samples)
print(counts)

This gives as an output a dictionary of the form:
{'00': 164, '01': 335, '11': 501}
Here the dict keys are the measure states, and the dict values are the number of times that state was measured.
You can see that the measurement returned 11 about half of the times, 01 about a third of the times, and 00 about a sixth of the times.
